# autocomplete results show up but cant find uppercase letters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, uppercase

The autocomplete is almost working as it should, except for a problem with words that start with an Uppercase.

for example the word 'Brussels':

I will be able to find it when I start typing in the searchbox 'russels', but 'Bru...' will not be found.

looking for words starting with a lowercase is not a problem, 'brussels' will show up once i start typing 'bru'.

Also words like New York will not show up when i start tying 'York', but will when i type 'ork'.

Search.php file

```
<?php
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName= "vlucht";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

$id = $_GET['q'];
$sql = "SELECT discipline FROM overzicht where discipline like '%".$id."%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo $row["discipline"]. "\n";
 }
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
 <script>
 jQuery(function(){
 $("#search").autocomplete("search.php");
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 Discipline : <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Geef je discipline in">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the collation on the database/table?

Comment: Aside: you're wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attacks.

Comment: Strange - it works just fine for me !?!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `LIKE` is usually case insensitive, unless you are using a collation (e.g. binary) where that would not be the case.  Assuming that, for whatever reason, your collation is causing `LIKE` to be case sensitive, here is one way you may phrase your query to behave the way you want:

```
$id = $_GET['q'];
$disc = "%" . strtolower($id) . "%";
$sql = "SELECT discipline FROM overzicht WHERE LOWER(discipline) LIKE ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $disc);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note that I am switching to using prepared statements with `mysqli`, which avoid things like SQL injection, to which your current script is prone.

Comment: @Dharman I reworked my answer so that I am now directly binding a PHP string variable to the statement.  All of the tutorials I read on mysqli statements are doing this.